# How do I mock a custom property of the window object in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, window

I'm building a ReactJS 17 app and trying to test that the following call happened with Jest.  The property "dataObj" is one I added to the global window object.

```
window.dataObj.send(event.name, ldo);
```

I'm trying this in my test ...

```
  const dataObj = {
    send: jest.fn()
  };
    
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'dataObj', dataObj);
  console.log(window.dataObj);
```

But when I query "window.dataObj" (using that console.log statement) it is always returning undefined.  How do I mock the property of the window object?

Comment: You don't need defineProperty unless the property has been defined with one before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign `dataObj` to the `value` of the descriptor.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
export function main(event) {
  window.dataObj.send(event.name, 'ldo');
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from './';

describe('66574843', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const dataObj = {
      send: jest.fn(),
    };

    Object.defineProperty(window, 'dataObj', {
      value: dataObj,
    });

    main({ name: 'teresa' });
    expect(dataObj.send).toBeCalledWith('teresa', 'ldo');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66574843/index.test.js
  66574843
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.755 s
```